# JavaScript - check if condition stays true for 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I have an array with two objects that changes constantly(lets say 5 times per second). Now I want to check if a certain condition is met over a period of time(5 seconds).

Let's say that is my array:

```
let array = [
        {
            "className": "state1",
            "probability": 0.9995008707046509
        },
        {
            "className": "state2",
            "probability": 0.0004989791777916253
        }
    ]
```

I want to trigger a function when `array[1].probability` stays above `0.8` for 5 seconds. How do I do this? Remember that if the probability drops below `0.8`, the "timer" has to start all over again.

***EDIT:***
Here is my complete code:

```
<div>Teachable Machine Image Model</div>
<button type="button" onclick="init()">Start</button>
<div id="webcam-container"></div>
<div id="label-container"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.3.1/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/image@0.8/dist/teachablemachine-image.min.js"></script>
<script src="watch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // More API functions here:
    // https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/image

    // the link to your model provided by Teachable Machine export panel
    const URL = "https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/AaMO5jL6/";

    // threshold for state to be active
    const THRESHOLD = 0.8;

    let model, webcam, labelContainer, maxPredictions;


    // Load the image model and setup the webcam
    async function init() {
        const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
        const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";

        // load the model and metadata
        // Refer to tmImage.loadFromFiles() in the API to support files from a file picker
        // or files from your local hard drive
        // Note: the pose library adds "tmImage" object to your window (window.tmImage)
        model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
        maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();

        // Convenience function to setup a webcam
        const flip = true; // whether to flip the webcam
        webcam = new tmImage.Webcam(200, 200, flip); // width, height, flip
        await webcam.setup(); // request access to the webcam
        await webcam.play();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        // append elements to the DOM
        document.getElementById("webcam-container").appendChild(webcam.canvas);
        labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) { // and class labels);
            labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        }
    }

    async function loop() {
        webcam.update(); // update the webcam frame
        const prediction = await predict();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }


    // run the webcam image through the image model
    async function predict() {
        let stateActive;
        // predict can take in an image, video or canvas html element
        const prediction = await model.predict(webcam.canvas);
        stateActive = prediction[1].probability > THRESHOLD;

        // DO STUFF WHEN stateActive is true for 5 seconds


        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
            const classPrediction =
                prediction[i].className + ": " + prediction[i].probability.toFixed(2);
            labelContainer.childNodes[i].innerHTML = classPrediction;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What causes the array to change? Is there an event/callback that is triggered whenever the values change? If you simply poll your array using setInterval/setTimeout there may be a chance that you miss an update and thereby create a false positive.

Comment: I've updated my post. The array change comes from window.requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have some sort of callback every time the value changes.

You can use `Date.now()` to get the current time in milliseconds. So it's easy to do math on that and see if 5000 milliseconds have passed.

With that you can just record the time when it's goes above, clear the time when it goes below, and if it hasn't been cleared for 5 seconds, then you know you're good.

```
const threshold = 0.8
const requiredTime = 5000
let wentAboveThresholdAt = null

someDataSource.onNewData(probability => {
  // Is the data above the threshold?
  if (probability > threshold) {

    // If it was previously was below threshold, then wentAboveThresholdAt
    // will be null. So just set it to the current time and wait for the next value.
    if (!wentAboveThresholdAt) {
      wentAboveThresholdAt = Date.now()
    }

    // Check if it's stayed above the threshold for the required time.
    else if (wentAboveThresholdAt + requiredTime < Date.now()) {

      // Success!
      console.log('was above threshold for required time!')
    }
  } else {

    // Below threshold, clear wentAboveThresholdAt so that when it goes above
    // the threshold the timer will start.
    wentAboveThresholdAt = null
  }
})
```

Comment: I've updated my initial post. Could you take another look? I had it almost working with your code - but just almost

Answer (score 0):

```
let timesGood = 0;

let array = [
    {
        "className": "state1",
        "probability": 0.9995008707046509
    },
    {
        "className": "state2",
        "probability": 0.0004989791777916253
    }
]

setTimeout(checkStatus, 200);

function checkStatus(){
    if(array[1].probability > 0.8){
        timesGood++;
        if(timesGood >= 25){
            // Code here for condition met for 5 seconds.
        }
    } else{
        timesGood = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(checkStatus, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to showcase the callback trigger, the code always sets probability of the first object above than 0.8.

```js
let count = 0;
const threshold = 0.8;

function getArray() {
  return [
    {
      className: "state1",
      probability: Math.random() + 0.8
    },
    {
      className: "state2",
      probability: Math.random()
    }
  ];
}

function callback() {
  count = 0;
  console.log('callback triggered!');
}

function checkArray() {
  let arr = getArray();
  document.getElementById("td_1_1").innerText = arr[0].className;
  document.getElementById("td_1_2").innerText = arr[0].probability;
  document.getElementById("td_2_1").innerText = arr[1].className;
  document.getElementById("td_2_2").innerText = arr[1].probability;
  if (arr[0].probability > threshold) {
    count++;
    if (count >= 25) {
      callback();
    }
  } else {
    count = 0;
  }
}
setInterval(checkArray, 200);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app">
  <table id="tableMain" class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>ClassName</td>
       <td>Probability</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td id="td_1_1"></td>
     <td id="td_1_2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td id="td_2_1"></td>
     <td id="td_2_2"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>

 <script src="src/index.js">
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```